# Arrays list in Java

Tags: java, csv, arraylist

I'm trying to insert data into a CSV file in Java, and i want to do it with an array list. Currently I'm inserting each line to the file with array list. How can i do it with a loop that running on arrays list? The main goal is to get the number of the rows as parameter, and then to let the loop to insert the data. That way i can control the number of the rows. Currently it's hard codded to 3 rows.

Here is my code. How can i improve it?

```
ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

data.add(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}); //line 1
data.add(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}); //line 2
data.add(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"}); //line 3

writer.writeAll(data); //inserting the data into the CSV file
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `for` loop:

```
    ArrayList<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    addRows(3);
    writer.writeAll(data);

    public void addRows(int rows){
             for(int i=0; i<rows; i++ ){
                  data.add(new String[] {"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"});
             }
        }
```

Comment: Toda neshama :-) I'm new in Java, so sometime i need help with basic stuff as well.

Comment: Can you please show me how to make this code to a nested arrays list? I want to insert the data cell by cell.

Answer (score 0):

This creates a list and adds values to the list.
Then I interate through the list using a while loop.

```
List<String> allTestResults = new ArrayList<>();
    allTestResults.add(varEnvironment);
    allTestResults.add(varFeaturName);
    allTestResults.add(varScenarioName1);
    allTestResults.add(varScenarioName2);
    allTestResults.add(varScenarioStatus);
    //Interate through the list 
    Iterator<String> iterator = allTestResults.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println("Test Results : " +iterator.next());
    }
```